# How to get CDN with @ in it in CSHTML(Razor) page

Tags: razor, cdn

How to get CDN with @ in it in CSHTML(Razor) page

lets suppose we have @ in the CDN and we want that script in CSHTML(Razor) page

[image]

but its giving error

[image]

how can i add this CDN as script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced same issue while working in a .Net Core app.

You need to escape the @ symbol inside the cdn url. Simply replace @microsoft with @@microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

`@` is its own escape character. Simply put in `@@`. Alternatively you can store the URL as a string variable and use that.